# How to select filtering by associated entries collection in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have many-to-many relationships for users and roles and I want to select user which have specific roles using realtions.
For example I want to get user having:

```
roles = ["role_1", "role_2", "role_3"]
```

so I tried

```
query.filter(Users.roles.contains(roles))
```

(where roles - List[Roles])

but I got

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapped instance expected for relationship comparison to object.   Classes, queries and other SQL elements are not accepted in this context; for comparison with a subquery, use Users.roles.has(**criteria).
```

then I tried

```
    query.filter(Users.roles.has(Roles.name.in_(roles)))
```

where roles already List[str]

And I got

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: 'has()' not implemented for collections.  Use any().
```

but any() selects entry that has any associated role when I need entry that has all required roles. So how to select it right way using relationships instead of joins and etc.?

```
  class Users(sa.Model):
__tablename__ = 'users'

id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
login = Column(String(50), unique=False)

roles = relationship('Roles', secondary='user_roles_map',
                     cascade='all, delete')


class Roles(sa.Model):
__tablename__ = 'roles'

id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
name = Column(String(40), unique=True)



class UserRolesMap(sa.Model):
__tablename__ = 'user_roles_map'

id_seq = Sequence(__tablename__ + "_id_seq")
id = Column(Integer(), id_seq, server_default=id_seq.next_value(),
            unique=True, nullable=False)
user_id = Column(
    Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'),
    primary_key=True)
role_id = Column(
    Integer, ForeignKey('roles.id'),
    primary_key=True)
```

Comment: Do you want to retrieve users who *only* have roles 1, 2, and 3, or do you want users who have *at least* those three roles (and possibly others)?

Comment: at least those three roles

Comment: no, sorry, actually I more intrested in only specific roles, without others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find what I was looking for, so for now I just wrote it with joins:

```
    query = db_session.query(Users) \
        .filter_by(**parameters)
        .join(UserRolesMap, UserRolesMap.user_id == Users.id)\
        .filter(UserRolesMap.role_id.in_(roles_ids))\
        .group_by(Users)\
        .having(func.count(UserRolesMap.role_id) >= len(roles_ids))
```

where roles_ids was collected from Roles table before. And if you need user with only required roles you can replace ">=" with "==".

Comment: Is there a way to use another ORM Objects (such as `Roles`) in place of its id (`roles_ids`)? For example `filter(UserRolesMap.roles.in_(Roles)`